# PHP preg_replace question?

Tags: php, preg-replace

hey guys,
I'm a preg_replace noob and don't understand how to solve the following case:

```
$youtubeurl = "((http|https)\:\/\/(www|it|co\.uk|ie|br|pl|jp|fr|es|nl|de)\.youtube\.(com|it|co\.uk|ie|br|pl|jp|fr|es|nl|de)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*))"; 
$content = preg_replace($youtubeurl, embedCode($youtubeurl), $content);
```

I have a pattern that matches any youtube URL.
If this pattern is matched i want to call the function embedCode() and pass along the matched string.

How can i do this. right now i'm obviously passing along the regexp code which is of course wrong. I need to pass along the matched string.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Comment: and how would this work? what do i pass along my function then?

Comment: @mathiregister: Read the documentation. The callback gets an array of matches, so to get the full URL, you'd have to combine the parts again. E.g. in the callback you could do: `return embedCode(implode('', $matches));`.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$youtube_url_pattern = "#((http|https)\:\/\/(www|it|co\.uk|ie|br|pl|jp|fr|es|nl|de)\.youtube\.(com|it|co\.uk|ie|br|pl|jp|fr|es|nl|de)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*))#"; 

if(preg_match($youtube_url_pattern, $content_containing_url, $content)){
  embedCore($contet[index]);
}
```

You just have to find the index of matched url, try `print_r($content);` inside the `if` and see what is the index for the matched pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do this:

```
if ( preg_match( '/' . $youtubeurl . '/', $content, $match ) )
{
    embedCode( $match );
}
```